# Is it possible to subscribe change feed of multiple containers in single azure function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to subscribe changefeed of multiple azure cosmos db containers in single azure function. In documentation a CosmosDBTrigger only accepts single databaseName and collectionName

Is there any option so that we can provide multiple collectionName and databaseName in runtime to monitor for change in azure function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2) is right, single Azure function supports multiple cosmos db containers can't be implemented so far.You need to configure specific container information with every azure function cosmos trigger.

I presume that you need to do some business if some columns which is respective stored in the multiple cosmos db are all updated. If so, i provide my rough idea here:

Create multiple azure function triggers to respective connect with multiple cosmos db containers to monitor them. If any updates occur, call one common http endpoint to store the key information into Azure table or SQL database or something like that. Then judge if all the specific column updated, do your business.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, Actually i am looking for a solution for a multi tenanted system where each tenant will have different db and collection for each microservices. 

We need to get change from each tenants database and then process that change. 

There is one way to write a CustomCosmosDbTrigger which will get db information from Host database and then listens for change for each tenants db, but problem with this is that in production we will have thousands of tenants. and a single trigger listining to thousands of dbs can be problem.

Comment: @ManishSingh have you addressed this issue? found any solution? tks